# How to cache output? (like ob_start() in php)

Tags: ruby

How to cache "puts" and "print" results, and save it to variable. Like `ob_start()` and `ob_get_contents()` in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'stringio'

save_so, $stdout = $stdout, StringIO.new(' ', 'w')
puts 'how now brown cow'
my_so, $stdout = $stdout, save_so

p [:saved_result, my_so.string]
puts 'and this works once again'
```

Comment: By the way, my version (in the answer) actually prints things whilst caching them. :) Not sure if it's important for OP or not.

Comment: @Sergio nice function, but don't called it `with_cached_output` - it's not caching, it's redirection.

Answer (score 2):

Some people will probably post clever solutions that utilize part of ruby standard library that I'm not familiar with. I can only offer you this one little dirty monkey patch:

```
module Kernel
  alias_method :old_puts, :puts

  def puts txt
    @cached_output ||= ''
    @cached_output += "#{txt}\n"
    old_puts txt
  end

  def cached_output
    @cached_output
  end
end

puts 'foo'
puts 'bar'
cached_output # => "foo\nbar\n"
```